# Thunderbird keeps asking me for the password every time I login

Tags: password, thunderbird

I haven't used Thunderbird for a while but when I started to use it again I found out that I have to give the application driven password since I'm using Gmail. So I type that application password which is automatically given by Google, but it asks for that every time I try to login.

It's really frustrating as to obtain that password I have to go to Google account settings every time I log into Thunderbird.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking the box next to "remember this password" in the password dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative issue is when transferring a profile from one machine to another, especially Windows to Linux, where some of the settings are 'hidden'. The error/dialog message simple asks for the password, and says nothing about failure to connect, if that's of note.

In particular the pkcs11.txt file contains a file path that needs converting to the linux absolute file path. Given that it's a convenience file, it's easier to delete/rename the file and let it be recreated at next start up.

It may also have line ending or special character issues if you try editing it.

Comment: deleting this file resolved my issue when migrating profile from windows 10 to linux

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you switch on the `remember this password` checkbox in the password dialog.
2. After entering the password check the password below "Settings/Security/Password".
3. Check also `signon.rememberSignons` in `about:config` (or with shutdown thunderbird in the file `prefs.js`.

See also this pages for some more ideas: [Password not remembered - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_not_remembered_%28Thunderbird%29)

Comment: @mr_mohamed: If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same trouble, moment in life. The best way to fix this problem would be to delete all your accounts with the mailing program, on Ubuntu. Start out fresh all the way.

1. Delete all accounts in the Ubuntu mailing program.
2. Go to Passwords and Keys program in the dash.
3. Delete that information.
4. Run apt-get update terminal
5. Run disk analyse
6. Log off, all the automatic logins like google, yahoo. Firefox->Edit>Preferences>Privacy top bar.
7. Restart the whole system.
8. Create all accounts again. Plus check the mark that says remember password.

This should work.

Good Luck

Comment: Isn't this a little bit overkill ?

Comment: Suitable as a last resort.

Comment: Except if you had 12 mail accounts and ditto calendars shared

Comment: Really? That is a lot of emails, you might need to get in contact with Canonical. Or you might want to contact a administrator with help with Ubuntu in the chat rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Thunderbird will prompt for password if:

1. The stored password is incorrect; **OR**
2. Thunderbird detects a different server, hostname, or IP address (than noted on previous successful attempts).

---

***POSSIBLE SOLUTION(S)***

- Try disabling the **remember this password**, and restarting (a least once);
- (If that fails) Ask the service provider (or ISP) to **reset your password**;
- (Failsafe method) **Create a new account** for this mailbox, and (when it is working) copy all existing folders/email across.

Answer (score 0):

The only real solution for me was using this great **ADD-ON**: https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/thunderbird/addon/master-password/

It gives you total control over the MASTER password, that was being asked several times (for each account?) on each thunderbird startup, and the prompt for the GOOGLE account password (already SAVED!) was also fixed.